# How to store the barcode image generated from barcodescanner in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am using barcodescanner.js plugin in my phonegap app and everything is working great for the following code.

```
 var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");

  scanner.encode(scanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, 123456789, function(success) {
             alert("encode success: " + success);
           }, function(fail) {
             alert("encoding failed: " + fail);
           });
```

The barcode image is displayed through this line

> alert("encode success: " + success);

Now I like to store this image into my local db or lets say create a new screen and show there. How do I get handle to the image from this "success" data. I tried to see the API in github and over internet but no one talks about it. Perhaps I am missing a big point here?? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I also noticed that I do not see alert("encode success:") either. not sure if the function(success) is getting executed properly.

Answer (score 2):

a bit late, but maybe useful for others:
The successcallback of the encode() function is never called. The encoding is done by means of an Intent which actually relaunches the app and hands off the encoding to a different activity. There is no way for your app to get hold of the generated image.

I am considering creating an additional function for this plugin which does invoke the successcallback with a base64 encoded QR code.

Comment: Any updates about your contribution?
I am facing the same issue and I want to solve this issue.
Thanks.